# Is there a lock-free vector implementation?

Tags: c++, vector, concurrency, lock-free, concurrent-vector

First result in Google for "lock free vector" is a research paper cowritten by Damian Dechev, Peter Pirkelbauer and Bjarne Stroustrup describing a theoretical lock-free vector. Has this, or any other lock-free vector, been implemented?

Comment: Maybe [libcds](http://libcds.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Could the down voter explains himself?

Comment: @victor: To be honest, the suggested implementation (from reading the first few lines in the article you mention) is more of a deque than a vector. What are your real requirements? If you want anything that fulfills all of `std::vector` requirements the answer is simple: it cannot be done. Depending on what you don't need from `std::vector` it might be achievable (I did not downvote, but you should make your requirements explicit, and also, if you ask for *lock-less*, I don't understand why you *accept* an answer that performs *locking*)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: to be entirely fair, I thought tbb::concurrent_vector was lock-free.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I looked at the article, it is a vector and not a deque. A lock free vector definitely can be implemented. Generally, every locking algorithm can be turned into lock free by letting other threads continue the work that one thread started. See work by Maurice Herlihy. And this is exactly what the article is describing. That said, it's probably not worthwhile to have a lock free `resize` operation - and the rest of the operations are easily lock free anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS provides ppl::concurrent_vector and Intel provides tbb::concurrent_vector. On Windows at least ppl and tbb are part of the C-Runtime.

Comment: *Concurrent* and lock-free are quite different things

Comment: You are correct, concurrent and lock-free are not the same. I was under the impression the MS ppl implementation of concurrent_vector was lock-free. Is this not so?

Comment: I tend to assume that unless otherwise specified no library is lock-less, and I have not seen any reference in a quick look at the documentation stating that ppl::concurrent_vector is lock-less.

Comment: I went through the implementation found in concurrent_vector.h, it appears to be a mix of locked and lock free parts. The interesting bit is pushing and popping when reallocation and compaction is unnecessary, lock free operations occur.

Answer (score -9):

I've just looked up what a vector is, in the wikipedia.

I think (only a minute or two of thinking, mind) a fully lock-free version is a bit problematic.

Consider; you create the array, access it as per normal, etc.  For this you do not need lock-free.  The problem them comes when you need to resize.  The thread which comes in and discovers this needs to malloc.  This is a truly unique operation - other threads at this point must block/spin.  If they tried to help, e.g. do the malloc themselves, you could have many threads issuing the malloc.  Now it might be in practise the number of threads doing is this is so low it's okay - in which case you may have a number of threads performing the malloc, with the winner atomically activating the new memory and the losers seeing this and then free()ing their memory.

Then to perform the copy, when a thread comes to access an element, well, we'll need to keep track of *all* of the allocated arrays in a list, and we access them through the list, oldest first, till we find the element we want and if it's not in the most recent array, we move it and then access it.

We then also need a way for a thread to know it has moved the final element and can free that array, so we'll have to count elements; so we have a risk of potentially unbounded allocation requirements.  What's more, the data structure (I've said a list, but it could be other things, although they won't be as good, prolly) will need to be atomic (since maybe threads could delete an array at the same time) and an atomic lock-free list was until very recently the pinnacle of lock-free data structures, as complex as they get, requiring SMR and with a complex implementation.

(I say until recently - someone recently invented a lock-free red-black tree, the whole thing, add and delete!)

TBH, I don't understand why anyone would use a vector.  Why not just use a balanced binary tree or a hash?