# two dimension STL vector thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, stl, thread-safety, stdvector

Suppose I have a 2 dimension vector

```
  vector< vector< int> > v
```

Then thread 1 operates on v[0], like

```
 v[0].push_back(x)
```

thread 2 operates on v[1],

```
 v[1].remove(y)
```

etc.

Is this operation thread safe? I suppose it is, as `v[0]` and `v[1]` are separate pointers which point to different memory address? Will these two pointers finally overlap?

Comment: v[0] and v[1] are different vectors, and the [] operator is safe when accessing different elements. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/

Comment: However, since v[0] and v[1] are adjacent in memory, accessing them repeatedly (I mean the objects themselves not their data) from two different threads may be bad for concurrent performance.

Comment: can you explain more about concurrent performance, why? since they are in cache, isn't good to have this for data locality?

Comment: False sharing. 'v' is a vector object which points to a block of contiguous memory containing the vector objects v[0], v[1], ... . Since the memory is contiguous, v[0] and v[1] reside in the same cache line (in different cores). Modification invalidates the cache line. https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads

Comment: since operations v[0].push_back or v[1].remove will not change the address v[0], v[1] pointed to, there is no false sharing

Comment: They change v[0] and v[1] themselves - they change the internal length fields. Since v[0] and v[1] are adjacent to each other in memory, this will cause false sharing. You are also wrong in that v[0].push_back will change the memory pointed to by v[0], irrelevant though that is - how else would it copy the argument into the vector?

Comment: That helps a lot! Thanks!

Comment: I can use array of vector pointers to get rid of false sharing.

Comment: Yes but be careful how you allocate the vectors - if they end up next to each other in memory anyway then you'll have the same problem. Don't worry this stuff unless it's definitely performance critical code though :)

Answer (score 0):

Use concurrent_vector provided by Intel.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506203

Comment: I want lock free, all TBB concurrent data structure contains locks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9385969/is-there-a-lock-free-vector-implementation